# Implement Password Reset in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

How could I implement password reset in Node.js, express.js and Mongodb? I want to send user an email with password reset link which is valid for one hour or two. Is there any existing library that supports this? How could I implement it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could actually be a framework agnostic question. I got a lot of information out of this screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password I know it's Ruby code but the techniques described there were easy to port to node.js.

Comment: this doesn't translate to node + express too well. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/SAl5F8qInfA

Comment: @chovy You say it doesn't translate well and then you link to a thread that has nothing to do with my answer. Why doesn't it translate too well?

Answer (score 0):

If you're up for using a third-party system, the Stormpath express library covers this in their docs here: https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/product.html#use-password-reset

I work on this library @ Stormpath, but it covers this use case pretty well. The only other options I'm aware of is to write this stuff raw from scratch.